# Short hand to change variable with function

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there's a way of changing some variable value with the return of some function. A short-hand-way of doing it.

If I want to add some value to a variable and changing it, we do like that:

```
let numb = 5;
numb *= 2; // Returns 10
```

But lets say I have a function that return the double of its argument like this:

```
function double(a) {
  return a * 2;
}

let numb = 5;
numb = double(numb); // Short hand of doing this line <----
```

Comment: Don't think there's anything shorter than your example, if the item being passed is a primitive (immutable)

Comment: I agree with @CertainPerformance. The only "short hand" you could add is using the `double(numb)` directly without reassigning it to a value.

Comment: JavaScript always uses call by value in case of primitives. So, the returned value will always need to be assigned to the variable making it at least this long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand how reference and value parameters work. When you pass in a number or a string to a function that is a value parameter and changing the value of the parameter withing the function has no effect on the variable that was passed in. If the parameter is a reference to an object then changes to properties on that object will then change the variable passed in.

```
let x = 5;
someFunc(x);
```

There is no way for someFunc to change x because the value 5 of x was passed into the function, not a reference to x;

```
let x = { prop: 5 };
someFunc(x);
```

Now if the body of someFunc changes x.prop then it will also change it to the variable x that was passed in because a reference to an object instance was passed in.

It is the same as assigning variables.

```
let x = 5;
let y = x;
```

Now x and y are both 5 but changing y = 6 does not effect x.

```
let x = { prop: 5 };
let y = x;
```

Now y is a reference to the same object so y.prop = 6 will change x as well.

All that aside good programming principles and modern functional programming concepts dictate that modifying parameters passed into functions is not good practice.

Comment: I got it now. Appreciate that sir!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an arrow key function. Saves a line or two.

```
const double = a => a * 2;

let numb = 5;
numb = double(numb);
```

Removing the short hand, the double function would look like

```
const double = (a) => {
  return a * 2
}
```

Arrow key functions are pretty much the same as a normal function, however they give you more control over the 'this' keyword.