# How can I do the same replace on multiple variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I want to do the same replace on multiple variables.  Here's an example that works, but I have to write the replace statement for each variable.  I could make the replace a function and call the function for each variable, but I was wondering if there's a more efficient way to do it in one line, something like `string1,string2,string3(replace...`

```
<script>
string1="I like dogs, dogs are fun";
string2="The red dog and the brown dog died";
string3="The dog likes to swim in the ocean";
string1=string1.replace(/dog/g,'cat');
string2=string2.replace(/dog/g,'cat');
string3=string3.replace(/dog/g,'cat');

alert(string1+"\n"+string2+"\n"+string3);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an array instead, and `.map` to a new array, carrying out the `replace` operation on each:

```js
const dogToCat = str => str.replace(/dog/g,'cat');
const strings = [
  "I like dogs, dogs are fun",
  "The red dog and the brown dog died",
  "The dog likes to swim in the ocean"
];
console.log(
  strings
    .map(dogToCat)
    .join('\n')
);
```

If you *have* to use standalone variables and reassign to them, then you can destructure the result, though it's ugly and probably isn't a great idea (`const`s are preferable, when possible):

```js
const dogToCat = str => str.replace(/dog/g, 'cat');
let string1 = "I like dogs, dogs are fun";
let string2 = "The red dog and the brown dog died";
let string3 = "The dog likes to swim in the ocean";

([string1, string2, string3] = [string1, string2, string3].map(dogToCat));
console.log(string1 + "\n" + string2 + "\n" + string3);
```

Comment: thanks, I do need to keep the variables intact, but that doesn't really simplify it like I hoped

Comment: If you have to reassign each individual variable, there's no way around writing out the variable name twice (see similar issue asked [an hour ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53698079/short-hand-to-change-variable-with-function)) - the `.map` shortcut plus destructuring is pretty much the only "shortening" option you have (feel free to remove the named callback if you want to conserve characters)